# Throws Security Exception on server , runs on localhost

Tags: asp.net, exception

While running my project on localhost , it is working Good . But when I deployed it on my server , I am getting this type of error . 
Error : 
Description: `The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.`

Comment: What are you expecting? You just posted the error you got without _any_ further comment... Do you think anybody's gonna answer this "question"?

Comment: please mark up so that I can remove question ban

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's getting cause of server security level limitation, you need to
>   fixed this in your `Web.Config` file.

or

> you can asked to Serve Vendor to change the Security Level for your
>   Host.

```
<system.web>
  <securityPolicy>
    <trustLevel name="Full/High/Medium/Low/Minimal" policyFile="internal"/>
  </securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

See the Reference [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: After applying these settings getting this error :
Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.

Comment: Thanks ! I contacted big rock .. they changed the access to full .. Now its working :)